# what are some good css shorthands you can think of?

Tags: css, forms, stylesheet, short, shorthand

some that i can think of are

font: bold 20px Verdana, sans-serif   /* one line for variant, size, and family */

color: #336  /* short color code */

height: 0   /* no need to specify unit when 0 */

border: 0  /* same effect as border: none but shorter */

background: #ffc  /* no need to use background-color if all is wanted is color */

padding: 0; border: 0; margin: 0  /* to show only content but nothing else */

border: 1px dashed #ff0  /* thickness, style, and color */

margin: 0 0.5em  /* specify top, bottom, left, right margin */

Comment: shorthands can be great, but watch out, they will overwrite all of the applicable properties even if you don't specify them.   For example:  "border: solid 1px"  will also reset "border-color" even though you didn't mention it.

Comment: Dustin Diaz has [an excellent CSS shorthand guide](http://www.dustindiaz.com/css-shorthand/).

Answer (score 3):

```
 1. background: #fff url(image.png) no-repeat 20px 100px fixed;
 2. ul { list-style: decimal-leading-zero inside; }
```

**Comma separated declarations**

1. h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { font-family:Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif; }

**First-child selectors**

```
 1. .footer em:first-child { color:#ccc; }
```

**CSS3 features**

**Rounded box with a radius**

1. `.rounded_corner { -moz-border-radius:10px; -webkit-border-radius:10px; width:400px; height:100px; background-color:#000; }`

**Shadow effect**

.shadow { width:400px; height:200px; background-color:#000; -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px #ccc; }

Comment: Neat stuff, but only the first two are actually shorthands.

Comment: background is my favorite, so I second it

Answer (score 0):

You can also specify the line height with the font property

```
font: bold 20px/1em Verdana, sans-serif /* one line for variant, size, and family */
```

Where 1em is the line height

Answer (score 0):

Outline's another one:

```
outline:3px dotted gray;
```

list-style supports images, too:

```
list-style:square inside url(image.gif);
```

Kinda redundant, but here's another article explaining them all:

http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200502/efficient_css_with_shorthand_properties/